# How to calculate the amount of possible numbers between 2 or more set of values that don't exceed a certain amount of value?

Tags: .net, algorithm, math, numbers, combinations

How can I calculate the amount of possible pairs of numbers from set of n values that don't exceed a certain amount of value when I sum up both elements of pair?

For example if we want to know the possible combinations between 2 sets of values between 0.1 and 100 we should calculate like 1000 x 1000 which is equal to 1 Million right? But how to get out of this 1 Million the combinations that don't exceed 100 (when you sum them) in an algorithmitic away?

For example:

- Both vectors X and Y can range between 0.1 and 100 (1000 possible numbers each)
- What are the possible combinations between vector X and Y of pairs which sum of elements  don't exceed 100?

Acceptable cases are:

[image]

Excluded cases are like:

[image]

And what about for a 3 case scenario or a n case scenario?

Is there any simple code to calculate this in .Net? or any simple mathematical formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is "amount", please describe this in more details, ideally provide an example input-> expected output (explanation)

Comment: The ouput should be the amount of possible combinations between 2 sets of values that don't exceed 100. For example if we want to know the possible combinations between 2 sets of values between 0.1 and 100 we should calculate like 1000 x 1000 which is equal to 1 Million right? But how to get out of this 1 Million the combinations that don't exceed 100 (when you sum them) in an algorithmitic away? This has been burning my brain the whole day :) and what about for 3 or more set of values? Maybe this is simple calculation and I'm missing something very basic

Comment: nice that you added your description of " that don't exceed 100 (when you sum them)". I suggest to add it to the question description. How one should guess what is "the amount of possible numbers between 2 or more set of values that don't exceed a certain amount of value?" This is terrible worded.

Comment: Yes... Because this is a terrible problem, there are no nice words to describe it, just to read and understand the title you have to burn your brain

Comment: Is 50+50 a valid pair?

Answer (score 1):

I will describe how to exclude a pairs that exceed 100 from a permutation of two elements pairs with repetitions made out of 1000 element ordered set. This is not clear however if you want to compute this or maybe just exclude such pairs out of arbitrary set of pairs. If later is the case then you have to simply iterate over them, count sum and compare.

---

If you differentiate between

`(a, b)`    and  `(b, a)`

this means that you are interested in permutations with repetitions.

There are 1000^2 such 2 elements pairs that you can make out of your 1000 elements set. They can be reordered as:

```
(0.1, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2), (0.1, 0.3), ... , (0.1, 99.8), (0.1, 99.9), (0.1, 100) // 1000
(0.2, 0.1), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.3), ... , (0.2, 99.8), (0.2, 99.9), (0.2, 100) // 1000
...
(100, 0.1), (100, 0.2), (100, 0.3), ... , (100, 99.8), (100, 99.9), (100, 100) // 1000
```

It is easy to see that there are 1000 * 1000 of them.

Now you can observe that when you put a limitation on them such that sum is less than or equals 100, it is easy to spot a rule when we reorder them as a sum: `(a+b)` instead of `(a,b)`:

```
(0.2), (0.3), (0.4), ... , (99.9), (100), (100.1)         // 1 is wrong
(0.3), (0.4), (0.5), ... , (100), (100.1), (100.2)        // 2 are wrong
...
(100.1), (100.2), (100.3), ... , (199.8), (199.9), (200)  // 1000 are wrong
```

Count them?

```
1000 * 1000 - (1 + 2 + ... + 1000) = 1 000 000 - (1+1000)*1000/2 = 
1 000 000 - 1 001 000 / 2 = 1 000 000 - 500 500 = 499 500
```

---

### Formula 1: The number of pairs with sum <= 100

In general following formula holds:

```
p = n^k - [ sum_(k-1)_n + n * ( n^(k-1) - ( n - k + 2))]
```

where:

- p - number of pairs with sum of elements <= 100
- k - number of elements in pair (i.e. 2)
- n - size of vector ( i.e. 1000)
- sum_(k-1)_n - sum of integers from k-1 to n = k-1 + k-1+1 + k-1+2 + ... + n = ( k-1 + n)* (n-k+2)/2

in case of n=1000, k=2: `p = 1000^2 - sum_(1)_1000`
in case of n=1000, k=3: `p = 1000^3 - [ sum_(2)_1000 + 1000 * ( 1000^2 - 999)]`

---

### Formula 2: The number of pairs with sum = 100

As you described in comments you are in fact interested in pairs with sum equal to `100`, not `<= 100`. Fine. In case you are interested in a number of pairs with `sum = 100` it is:

```
p = sum (i)_(k-1)_(n^(k-1)) of [ n^(k-1) - i)]
```

that is sum from `i = k-1` to `i = n^(k-1)` expressions of form `n^(k-1) - i`

which can be shortened to:

```
p = sum (j)_(0)_(n^(k-1) -k + 1) of j
```

that is sum from `j = 0` to `j = n^(k-1) -k + 1` integers `j`. This is the same as:

```
p = ( 1 + n^(k-1) -k + 1) * ( n^(k-1) -k + 1) / 2   // arithmetic series
```

No need to run loops, the math is simple  ; )

Comment: Yes is more or less this, I need some kind of code that makes this not just for 2 elements but also for more, like 10, or more

Comment: @MartinVerdas I have provided the formula

Comment: I don't understand this part " sum_(k-1)_n - sum of integers from k-1 to n" how to put this in code?

Comment: this is the sum of integers. For k =2 it is (1+1000)*1000/2, for k=3 it is (2+1000)*999/2. We use here a formula for a sum of arithmetic series.

Comment: @MartinVerdas You have a complete answer. Can I explain anything more to you?

Comment: I will review this, I'm trying some code, also from what the other user posted, I said something wrong before, I need only for cases where the sum is = 100 ( not <= 100), I will check this, thanks for the help, I will certainly upvote ;)

Comment: @MartinVerdas You have said "X and Y of pairs which sum of elements don't exceed 100" not is equal to 100. My answer is answer to what you said.

Comment: @MartinVerdas I have added formula for sum = 100. Please try this.

Comment: @MartinVerdas In the case where k = 10 you really want him to sum all j from 0 to 1000^9?

Comment: yes, this is correct: sum of 0 to 1000^9 - 9. Do you think this is not correct?

Comment: this is a closed form formula, a sum of integers. But you will use a shorthand for sum of arithmetic series (a0 + an)*n/2

Comment: @MartinVerdas Is there something I can explain more to you?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard:

```
SortedSet<Tuple<decimal,decimal>> set = new SortedSet<Tuple<decimal, decimal>>();
int n = 0 ;

for ( decimal a = 0.1m ; a <= 100m ; a += 0.1m )
{
  for ( decimal b = 100m - a ; b > 0m ; b -= 0.1m )
  {
    if ( a+b > 100m ) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    ++n ;
    set.Add(new Tuple<decimal,decimal>(a,b)) ;
  }
}
```

At the end of the day, *n* is 499,500.

Without building the `SortedSet` and timing it with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`, it runs (in the debugger) in about 4/100 second (0.040456 seconds). Building the `SortedSet` does take a little longer (2.47 seconds in the debugger).

Comment: Can you please explain why to do it when there is closed form formula which I described in my answer? Is this coincidence that you got also result of 499 500 ?  : p

Comment: It is kind like running loop over a vector to count its elements.

Comment: thanks for code, this is kind of what I need, I tried it for 2 cases like you posted it looks like works fine, but issue is that I need a case with 10 cases (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j), I placed more "Fors" inside the existing fors, with new variables (c, d, e,  etc...) but now this takes like forever (40 minutes passed and the "a" variable is still in 0.1) Any known way to speed this up? I was thinking maybe with LINQ there is a fastest way? But I can't find anything useful...